# Why isn't my class exposed to peer classes in the same namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to write a utility class that writes email messages as part of my web service.

I have it in my project's App_Code folder:

```
namespace OrtundService.Controllers
{
    public class ServiceMail
    {

    }
}
```

This class just basically gets model data from the controller that's calling it and uses that data to generate an email which I then send to the email address contained in the model record.

For reasons beyond my comprehension, though, I can't access this in the following controller:

```
namespace OrtundService.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {

    }
}
```

It's clear the 2 classes are peers in the same namespace, so why wouldn't the UsersController class be able to see the ServiceMail class?

For clarity on the matter, I have established that the ServiceMail class can see the UsersController class.

Comment: Are they on the same project? (project, not solution)

Comment: Yup, same project. It's the Web Api 2 project.

Comment: Check if the build property for the file in app_code is set to compile

Comment: `App_Code` is code that will be compiled *later*, when the website starts up. Essentially, all that code lives in a different assembly and it doesn't exist *yet*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the class out of app_code to it's own folder in your project.

Comment: That sorted it, but I'm confused. I don't know why the app_code folder was blocking it...

Comment: Damien's answer tells the exact reason. :)